# Entity Framework is throwing an error "Unable to evaluate the expression. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80070057."

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Entity Framework to get db data. I wrote an action to return table data in JSON format as below:

```
public JsonResult GetEmployeesData()
{
     using (TrainingDBEntities db = new TrainingDBEntities())
     {
           return new JsonResult { Data = db.Employees, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
     }
}
```

It's not throwing any exception. But a console error is occurring with error code: 500. When I debugged, it showed an error

> The function evaluation requires all threads to run

When I try to reload, a new error occurs:

> Unable to evaluate the expression. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80070057

I don't have any idea what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Can you share the full exception text incl. stacktrace? Anyways, I think it's a problem related to EF's lazy loading. So what what you could try is to replace `Data = db.Employees` with `Data = db.Employees.ToList()` to force EF to load the entities.

Comment: If "optimize code" is enabled in the project properties, this could be one cause of the error. Disable (uncheck) it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is :

```
public JsonResult GetEmployeesData()
{
     using (TrainingDBEntities db = new TrainingDBEntities())
     {
           var emps = db.Employees.ToList();
           return new JsonResult { Data = emps, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
     }
}
```

I think accessing db inside the JsonResult{} is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluation is working properly because you have not converted result set into a valid datatype for JSON.

You can replace below code

```
JsonResult { Data = db.Employees, JsonRequestBehavior = ..}
```

with

```
JsonResult { Data = db.Employees.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior = ..}
```