# azure entity framework issues with error code Unknown error: 0x80070057

Tags: azure, entity

I having issues with entity framework on Azure Database, I can open up the models and update the database entities but when I try to run the application the first data call get error Entity Framework is throwing an error “Unable to evaluate the expression. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80070057.”
I'm thinking if I can open the model up and update the entities i have the correct permissions.

I'm not getting the same issues when running localhost with localhost database.

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158753/entity-framework-is-throwing-an-error-unable-to-evaluate-the-expression-operat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework is throwing an error "Unable to evaluate the expression. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80070057."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158753/entity-framework-is-throwing-an-error-unable-to-evaluate-the-expression-operat)