# How to make a Connection between EF6 and asp.net core 3

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-3.0

Goal:
Use EF 6 inside of ASP.net core 3 by using a project named ef.
Project EF is the main connection to the database sql server.

Problem:
I get an error saying

> Error = Unable to evaluate the expression. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80070057.

What part am I missing from the code in order retrieve the data in asp.net core 3.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var ddf = _context.Blogs;


    return View();
}
```

Info:
*Uploaded the project at github (https://github.com/candyboyyy/WebApplication1_asp.netcore3)

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Blogs]
(
    [BlogId] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [NVARCHAR](200) NULL,
    [Url] [NVARCHAR](200) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Blogs] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BlogId] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

---

[image]

Comment: I suspect this is a dupe of [Entity Framework is throwing an error “Unable to evaluate the expression. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80070057.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158753/entity-framework-is-throwing-an-error-unable-to-evaluate-the-expression-operat) but the image showing the error message covers the code, so I can't be sure.

Comment: Why should not use Entity Framework Core? Why use Entity Framework?

Comment: From [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/what-is-new/#ef-630) ,There's currently no support for using the EF designer directly on .NET Core or .NET Standard projects.You can work around this limitation by adding the EDMX file and the generated classes for the entities and the DbContext as linked files to a .NET Core 3.0 or .NET Standard 2.1 project in the same solution. Reference:https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-3-0-preview-9-and-entity-framework-6-3-preview-9/

Comment: Post the code in the question itself, not a Github repo that can be deleted at any time. What you posted looks like a Debugger watch error, not a real exception. Did you get an exception? It could be that the debugger shows an error because it can't execute the query while the app is frozen

Comment: Your code doesn't contain any queries. A `DbSet` is *not* an IQueryable - it's not a query. It's the base used to create queries. If you want to load all stored entities use `_context.Blogs.ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest try to establish a database connection first from your web project to your database.  In your `Startup.cs` class, add this line of code `var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");` under `ConfigureServices.cs` class.  Then add `services.AddDbContext` to  configure your EF and add services to the container.

Code snippet below.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddControllersWithViews();

                var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

    services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString), ServiceLifetime.Transient);

            }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I get a error message when I use "services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options"

Comment: "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Suppression State
Error CS1061 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddDbContext' and no accessible extension method 'AddDbContext' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) WebApplication1 C:\candy2\WebApplication1_asp.netcore3\WebApplication1\Startup.cs 31  Active
"

Comment: An advise is to download the project at github and you will probably understand better.

Comment: @What'sUP try to add `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace in `Startup.cs` class.  `AddDbContext` is an extension method of `IServiceCollection` interface. I have updated the code snippet above.

Comment: The code "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" is already applied and I still get the same problem.

Comment: @Juniuz this question is specifically about Entity Framework 6, not Entity Framework Core, so the AddDbContext() method doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this article https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data/entity-framework-6.html

```
services.AddScoped((_) => new ApplicationDbContext(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).